# What's the regular expression to determine if the last two characters of string are 'R' and a number?

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to determine if a given string ends with 'R' and then a single digit (0-9) for instance TESTR3 would be what I'm looking for whereas TESTR34 would not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like so:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("R[0-9]$");
```

Edit: Reverted to `[0-9]` to avoid matching characters like `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`

Comment: This is tagged as C#, so C# is indeed relevant.

Answer (score 9):

The expression `R\d$` should work.

Comment: You don't need the `.*`, you can just do `R\d$`.

Comment: Thanks @ICR. I had that at first and second-guessed myself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like: R[0-9]$

http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx is always helpful as well.

Comment: R\d$ works as well. For some reason I just prefer using [0-9]. But \d is probably a better habit.

Comment: Depends on what you're looking for.  `[0-9]` matches exactly those characters.  `\d` is going to match `[0-9]` and any digits from other character sets. Chinese numerals, for example:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals